# How to run selenium java test in linux in non-headless mode through docker

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser, xvfb

I know it works fine when I run in headless mode.
However is it possible to run in non-headless mode?

I've installed xvfb through docker and setting

```
ENV DISPLAY=:99
```

While running the test

```
docker run -e Xvfb ${DISPLAY} gradle <task name>
```

It always gives the error as

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: '4c3a51d1d7', ip: '<ip>', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs', java.version: '1.8.0_222'
```

Comment: any update on this

Comment: I sorted it out. yes its possible. We just need to start xvfb before test starts.